# How to install System.Media with dotnet command

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have been having trouble with using System.Media, then I came across a forum post saying that you can install packages using dotnet add. I have no idea how to use this for my purpose as it comes up with, error: There are no versions available for the package 'System.Media'

Comment: It is a namespace name, not a package name.  To find the package, look at the docs for the class you intended to use.  Like [SoundPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=net-5.0) => System.Windows.Extensions

Answer (score 0):

Classes from the [System.Media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media?view=net-5.0) namespace are in *System.Windows.Extensions* assembly and the package has the same name.

If using `dotnet` then:

```
dotnet add package System.Windows.Extensions
```